# UIManager color at a JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, nimbus, uidefaults

I'm using Nimbus Look and Feel, with only 3 changes at its colors:

```
UIManager.put("nimbusSelection", new Color(164,164,164));
UIManager.put("nimbusSelectionBackground", new Color(214,217,223));
UIManager.put("nimbusSelectedText", Color.BLACK);
```

My FileChooser looks like this:

[image]

So selected file's name appears in white and looks bad, and it also happens for the file type selected at the combobox. I want to change it to Black, but nimbusSelectedText is already black and is not working.

I also had a look at the Nimbus Defaults guide at http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html#primary and i see no parameter at FileChooser or Combobox to fix this.

Any help identifying the necessary parameters? Thanks

Comment: 2nd. hint http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/ , but I think that required >= JDK1.6.020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is one way possible to do it. You can get the JList from your JFileChooser and modify it:

```
public boolean getJList(Container c)
{
    Component[] cmps = c.getComponents();
    for (Component cmp : cmps)
    {
        if (cmp instanceof JList)
        {
            modifyJList((JList)cmp);
            return true;
        }
        if (cmp instanceof Container)
        {
            if(getJList((Container) cmp)) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
private void modifyJList(JList list)
{
    // Here you can modify your JList
}
```

and to use it, just call `getJList()`:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
getJList(chooser);
```

Comment: What do you mean with "Modify"?

Comment: @Martijn change the background color for example?

Comment: Hmmm... Yes, maybe. Indeed: Stupid question :P

Comment: Works great... with the JList. My problem is with the JComboBox, which doesn't have getSelectionBackground method :(

Answer (score 2):

[JFileChooser](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) is compound [JComponent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/componentlist.html), you can extract `JButtons`, `JToggleButtons` and [JScrollPane with JViewPort that contains JList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724784/set-rtl-orientation-of-scrollbar-inside-jfilechooser/6725693#6725693), please download Darryl's [Swing Utils](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/swing-utils/) , read descriptions, then run (Darryl's) code, result is selection for JList or JTable (I voting for that)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalButtonUI;

public class CrazyFileChooser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new CrazyFileChooser().makeUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public void makeUI() {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        for (AbstractButton button : SwingUtils.getDescendantsOfType(AbstractButton.class, chooser)) {
            button.setUI(new XORButtonUI());
        }
        for (JList list : SwingUtils.getDescendantsOfType(JList.class, chooser)) {
            list.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        }
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    }
}

class XORButtonUI extends MetalButtonUI {

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
        g.setXORMode(Color.YELLOW);
        super.paint(g, c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know, but have you tried setting this properties:

```
List.selectionForceground
List.selectionBackground
```

A FileChooser looks pretty much like a list...

---

Second try. Maybe settings these helps:

```
controlHighlight
controlLHighlight
```