# Can't find UIManager key for filechooser

Tags: java, swing, internationalization, jfilechooser

I'm trying to develop a program in Java and I need to internationalize it.
I'm using Swing to create a JFileChooser, and everything works fine.
The problem is I can't seem to find the UIManager key that maps to the text of the label for the file name text field (the String circled in the screenshot).

[image]

I've already tried using UIManager.getDefaults() but I still can't find the key.

The code I use to display the JFileChooser is this:

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
fileChooser.setFileFilter(new FolderFilter());
int n = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AHF8.png)

EDIT: I've managed to find a way around this.
I'm iterating all the elements with

```
for (Component comp : fileChooser.getComponents()) {
```

then I keep exploring the tree until I can find the label I'm looking for. Really ungraceful solution, so I'm hoping to find a better one.

Comment: [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25479856/714968)