# Editable JComboBox Background color

Tags: java, swing

I have a editable combobox, but I am not able to change its background color. Tried

```
((JTextField) myJComboBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent())
#setBackground(Color.xxxx);
```

> ref:
>   [Change JComboBox colours WITHOUT renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844176/change-jcombobox-colours-without-renderer)

But it doesn't seem to work

Any ideas?

Comment: my idea is, that there ...., be sure with that, that there must be another problem,

Comment: just changed tt.setOpaque(true); and it seems to work fine

Comment: my curiosity, for why reason(s) you set Opacity, and for which of JComponents from JComboBox, because JComboBox have got lots of JComponents

Comment: was set for JComponent, JTextField editorJComp = (JTextField);    menuitems[i].getEditor().getEditorComponent();
        editorJComp.setBackground(Color.red);
        editorJComp.setOpaque(true);

Comment: See also [opacity](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html#props).

Comment: as far as I know, you can answer and accept your own question if you found a solution - more useful for others than to hide it in comments, IMO :-)